# Types of property 'X' are incompatible (when using string union)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have two components defined as following:

```
const GridCell = <T extends keyof FormValue>(
  props: GridCellProps<T>,
) => {
....
}

const GridRow = <T extends keyof FormValue>(props: GridRowProps<T>) => {
...
  <GridCell
    type={props.type} // <-- error here
    fractionDigits={props.fractionDigits}
    ...
    />
...
}
```

My types are defined as following:

```
export type GridRowFieldType<T extends keyof FormValue> = {
  isDetail: boolean;
  highlighted: boolean;
  label: string;
  fieldName: T;
} & (
  | { type: 'date' | 'duration'; fractionDigits?: never }
  | { type: 'number'; fractionDigits: number }
);

export type GridRowProps<T extends keyof FormValue> = {
  showDetails: boolean;
  values: FormValue[T];
} & GridRowFieldType<T>;


export type GridCellProps<T extends keyof FormValue> = {
  label: string;
  fieldName: T;
  index: number;
} & (
  | {
      type: 'date';
      value: DateFieldValueType | undefined;
      fractionDigits?: never;
    }
  | {
      type: 'duration';
      value: DurationFieldValueType | undefined;
      fractionDigits?: never;
    }
  | { type: 'number'; value: number | undefined; fractionDigits: number }
);
```

For some reason I get this error in the `GridCell` component:

```
Types of property 'type' are incompatible.
      Type '"number" | "date" | "duration"' is not assignable to type '"number"'.
        Type '"date"' is not assignable to type '"number"'.ts(2322)
```

Even though type always resolves as `"number" | "date" | "duration"`, I still get that error, and I have no idea why, and on how to resolve it.

**Edit:**

In `GridCellProps` if I change :

```
& (
  | {
      type: 'date';
      value: DateFieldValueType | undefined;
      fractionDigits?: never;
    }
  | {
      type: 'duration';
      value: DurationFieldValueType | undefined;
      fractionDigits?: never;
    }
  | { type: 'number'; value: number | undefined; fractionDigits: number }
);
```

To:

```
type: 'date' | 'duration' | 'number';
```

This error disappears, but I need to define the type of the `value` prop depending on the value of the `type` prop.

**Edit 2:**

Here is the TS playground (it looks a bit different, but the issue is the same):

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHsoFsBqcA2ArigN4CwAUMsjMBPgCYCMAXMgBQDOYUoA5sgA+yQiAYRaICAwCUAbQC6AbkrVa9BgCY27EISwAjaEJFiJoafOWqadRgGYdB9OnwQ4IE6PGTLilVS2GgAsOty8IALC3uZSsv426owArGE8-F5mvvHWFAC+lJRgAJ4ADigA4rwMqHYMADwAKsgQAB6QYpzIANYQxegwaJi4BMQAfMgAvMjkgfhwRvhs4fwBanUAcnBYEGyNAXnIAGQcNsKz1JfIJeVsAOSQ7XdrV8gAbqMQAPzL6ZEvVxgUEQYGA6BAABFgHxgGBOD9kFI3tAAcgCoFzjYrjddsg7s5XO4QM8sZcPkRvmwCW4PKi1MCEKDwVCYXCEUiUaT0dRztcyri7npDNBnu9Puz9EYoEoaAymZDobDOGwhVK0ZQZAEivzkFVgAwAEroADuUxmiTqyt11VqGnqvX6gww2DwFLGCXyWooCHB3CCjCtepqdXtfQGQxdn3dCjNchsF0u80W91tjGQTDuABpSUkGFsdvdcxns4FqDj7o8wFmbHkS9QE9Qk-QU3VkJpq6X-XntgLc+265dy3jVSKB-SQWCFayrUwB7XKLlKD6QH6sHBSqmGFb2EHN6HHRGRm6rGbc5wAHRr0rsdgwGRTCYJqAQMCEKCeBvIJtLGjn79jrt81xGBz1zICAKHECcQA8liDYEDYIgACgQnZlFTheDQLlScWSVGtKDyGQgA

Comment: I can not test because can not access typescript playground, but if you change the 3 types "date", "duration" and "number" by an enum (or const object as const) `enum ETYPES = { dt:"date", duration : "duration", num:"number"`. Then, replace your types in you component by, eg, `ETYPES.duration` or `ETYPES.num`
Does this work ? Because I guess the type "duration" in one component is not the same as "duration" in another although their values are siimilar

Comment: @Jerome, unfortunately this didn't solve the problem, I got the same error:

`Types of property 'type' are incompatible.
        Type 'ETYPES' is not assignable to type 'ETYPES.number'.
          Type 'ETYPES.date' is not assignable to type 'ETYPES.number'.ts(2322)`

Comment: @Jerome can you please check the TS Playground in my edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this error, the solution was to use a switch statement to check the type of each field and return an object with the appropriate properties based on the type, this ensures that we only assign the correct properties to fields of the appropriate type, here is the updated TS playground:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHsoFsBqcA2ArigN4CwAUMsjMBPgCYCMAXMgBQDOYUoA5sgA+yQiAYRaICAwCUAbQC6AbkrVa9BgCY27EISwAjaEJFiJoafOWqadRgGYdB9OnwQ4IE6PGTLilVS2GgAsOty8IALC3uZSsv426owArGE8-F5mvvHWFAC+lJRgAJ4ADigA4rwMqHYMADwAKsgQAB6QYpzIANYQxegwaJi4BMQAfMgAvMjkgfhwRvhs4fwBanUAcnBYEGyNAXnIAGQcNsKz1JfIJeVsAOSQ7XdrV8gAbqMQAPzL6ZEvVxgUEQYGA6BAABFgHxgGBOD9kFI3tAAcgCoFzjYrjddsg7s5XO4QM8sZcPkRvmwCW4PKi1MCEKDwVCYXCEUiUaT0dRztcyri7npDNBnu9Puz9EYoEoaAymZDobDOGwhVK0ZQZAEivzkFVgAwAEroADuUxmiTqyt11VqGnqvX6gww2DwFLGCXyWooCHB3CCjCtepqdXtfQGQxdn3dCjNchsF0u80W91tjGQTDuABpSUkGFsdvdcxns4FqDj7o8wFmbHkS9QE9Qk-QU3VkJpq6X-XntgLc+265dy3jVSKB-SQWCFayrUwB7XKLlKAB6JctKBQTDISg+kB+rBwUqphhW9hBo+hx0RkZuqxm3OcAB0+9K7HYMBkUwmCagEDAhCgngNsgTZLDQD4gWOXb5riMAPrm0GQUOsE4pB5LEGwsFoRAkFAhOzKKnCGFwXKk4skqNaUHkMiFBQK7IJwriEPK26+mAyDPkenAAMqMfKOhniGDrhs617jLe0z3k+B6vu+n7moEnDGrCCAABYcMh-IfkBCBwJwKAPG0VYsKS1A-n+AHya8iYLM2YEQSZlzwT2RFOTskHYvyREoQ51BYURWHuWiqI6XpeLUkSdzGZ2pm-v+gE+cBNmgbB9nRY5mzOWBrnYQlSEPt5aW+Z8-mfIFeTBbp+kjlAkUOWZcWWVZiXJnZSWBesGjQS5GVublnlgQVTVihSJUUu1sp4VOSouSR+HTmVLzolRShAA

Comment: nice solution, very readable btw